# Hands partially disappear when near main camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've created a model for hands in "Blender" and uploaded the model to "Unity". I have attached the hands' model to the main camera, but a problem occurs. The part of the hands that is near the camera simply disappears. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I would assume it's simply clipping through your near plane? Check what your near distance is in your camera settings. Bringing that back a bit may help.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on your Camera, there are two Clipping properties (Near and Far). Make sure "Near" is set to 0. Otherwise, things that are too close to the camera won't be displayed.

Comment: Do note that you can't actually set the near plane of a perspective camera to 0. The Unity editor will automatically reset it to 0.01 when you try to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your help, although your suggestion seemed to have fixed a part of a problem, there is still some disappearing in the shoulder area. Also I have created a weapon for this character which disappears at a certain limit so to say. For example if I turned downwards 45 degrees, the weapon would disappear and then appear when I cross that line. I know it seems kind of hard to understand but I have no idea how to explain it :D